# Error al intentar vaciar el contenido de CKeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy colocando en mi proyecto el **CKeditor 4.10** el paquete básico. Sin problema se me muestra y puede escribir y capturar los datos del el. Lo que me sucede es que a la hora de querer borrar los datos que están escrito dentro del editor no me lo esta borrando y me envía un error con **setData**. A continuación le dejo el código y el error para ver si me pueden ayudar.

**Error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

**Instancia de inicio y función de borrar los datos**

**HTML**

```
<textarea  name="editor1" id="comentario" rows="5" placeholder="Comentario" class="form-control border-input"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 if($("textarea#comentario").length > 0){
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

        function CKupdate(){
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('');
        }
    }
```

**Captura de datos y llamado a la función de limpieza de datos del editor**

```
var guardarcomentario = function(){

    $("#fidcoment").submit(function(e){

        if($("textarea#comentario").val() != ''){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataString = new FormData($(this)[0]);
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php?c=pendientes&f=comentario",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    //mientras enviamos el archivo
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        message = $("<div class='alert alert-error'><span class='before'>Subiendo, por favor espere...</span></div>");
                        $("div#iderrorc").html(message);      
                    },                                
                    success: function (datos) {
                        CKupdate();
                        $("div#iderrorc").html(datos);
                        $("input#idEnviar").prop('disabled', true);
                    },
                    //si ha ocurrido un error
                    error: function(){
                        message = $('<div class="alert alert-error">Ha ocurrido un error.</span>');
                        $("div#iderrorc").html(message);
                    }  
                }).done(function(info){
                       console.log( info ); 
                });            
        }

       return false; 
    });

}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Vacía el textarea.

```
$("#comentario").val("");
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias pero no me borra el texto del editor. Lo que sucede es que el CKeditor cambia las propiedades del **textarea** por lo que tengo que para borrarlo solo puede ser son **setData** al igual que para insertarle contenido.

Comment: Si, pero el texto que muestra se recoge como valor del textarea, así que sería de esperar que vaciarlo vaciara también el ckeditor, aunque parece que no funciona.

Comment: Has probado a pasar CKEDITOR.intances.editor1 como parámetro a la función?

Comment: Tampoco me trabaja me sigue enviando el error solo me quedaría intentar hacerlo con javascript puro

Comment: Parece que al ser setData asíncrono debes usar el callback si la llamas tras haber rellenado ya el textarea. Te paso el enlace [https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData]

Comment: Gracias @Carmen por tu ayuda ya lo logre resolver por alguna razón el problema estaba en que tiene que tener el mismo nombre, el atributo **name** y **id** del **textarea** si también vi eso que me comentas en la API de ahí y hice las pruebas y nada hasta ahora que hice este cambio

Comment: Curioso, no lo hubiera imaginado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto, es la mejor manera de vaciar el contenido de un textarea manejada con una instancia de ckeditor

```
 <script>
   CKEDITOR.instances['texto1'].setData('');
 </script>

<textarea id="texto1" name="texto1"></textarea>
```

Lo mejor es que puedes usarlo en eventos jquery, como un evento click,  o donde lo necesites, se que ya paso tiempo pero nunca es demasiado tarde. Espero a alguien mas le sirva